# Action Function not working in Communities

Tags: visualforce, community

I am unable to invoke ActionFunction in Communities, where as it is working fine in salesforce

Code:

```
<apex:actionFunction name="ActionFunc" action="{!registerUser}" reRender="myStatus" status="as">
    <apex:param name="firstParam"  assignTo="{!firstName2}" value=" " />
    <apex:param name="secondParam" assignTo="{!lastName2}" value="  " />
    <apex:param name="thirdParam" assignTo="{!dob2}" value="  " />
    <apex:param name="fourthParam" assignTo="{!gender2}" value="  " />
    <apex:param name="fifthParam" assignTo="{!street_adr1}" value="  " />
    <apex:param name="sixthParam" assignTo="{!city2}" value="  " />
    <apex:param name="seventhParam" assignTo="{!street_adr2}" value="  " />
    <apex:param name="eighthParam" assignTo="{!state2}" value="  " />
    <apex:param name="ninethParam" assignTo="{!zip2}" value="  " />
    <apex:param name="tenthParam" assignTo="{!email2}" value="  " />
    <apex:param name="elevenParam" assignTo="{!email_confirm2}" value="  " />
    <apex:param name="tweleveParam" assignTo="{!password2}" value="  " />
    <apex:param name="thirteenParam" assignTo="{!password_confirm2}" value="  " />
    <apex:param name="fourteenParam" assignTo="{!mobile2}" value="   " />
    <apex:param name="checkParam" value="" assignTo="{!checkParam2}" />
</apex:actionFunction>

<button id="" type="submit" onclick="Javascript:SaveUsername()" class="btn btn-primary btn-with-icon mobile-button-align-right cf">
    <span id="">next</span><span id="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right glyphicon-align-right"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: did you tried this solution? https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AqLqIAK

It is always better to explain your question in detail manner so can you post your code ?

Comment: When you say you are unable to invoke it, what's the error? Are you 100% sure it's not being called but you're hitting some kind of permissions issue in the code?

From a Javascript perspective there's no security enforced so I think it's likely to come down to profile somewhere. I assume that `SaveUsername` is calling `ActionFunc`?